# Error connecting to environment 1 Org Local Fabric: Error querying channels: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am unable to run my ibm evote blockchain application in hyperledger faric.I am using IBM Evote in VS Code (v1.39) in ubuntu 16. When I start my local fabric (1 org local fabric), I am facing above error.
following is my local_fabric_connection.json file code

```
{
    "name": "local_fabric",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:17051"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:17054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

and following is the snapshot
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your second image it doesn't look like your 1 Org Local Fabric started properly in the first place (you have no gateways and for some reason your wallets aren't grouped together!).

If you `teardown` your 1 Org Local Fabric then start it again hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell how to add gateway. When I am trying to add the gateway, VS code extension is asking to for a connection profile. I think connection profile is not made.  And I can't find how to add connection profile. If I am able to add connection profile I will be able to add gateway. So could you please tell how to add connection profile in VS Code Local extension

Comment: I am using local VS Code extension (not of ibm cloud). So I am running my network locally. I have also searched how to add connection profile but I found how to add connection profile in ibm cloud blockchain extension. But as I am running it locally, I am unable to figure out how to add my connection profile and then add gateway

Comment: If you create a local environment (e.g the 1 Org Local Fabric), then it should create the gateway. If it hasn't created the gateway, then that indicates that it was never created / started correctly. I suggest you teardown your environment, start it again, then post the logs here from the 'Blockchain' output.

Comment: now I am able to connect and run my local network. But when I am running invoke.js file using node invoke.js, it is saying "no suitable peers to initialize from". Although all the containers of orderer,peer and certificate autority are running successfully. If I am not wrong, is the eror occuring because the network can't find the url and port number of orderer,peer,ca docker containers. If it is so where can I add the url of those container so that network can find them. thanks